# Loading JSON using AJAX jsonp yields no result

Tags: jquery, html, json, flask

I have a flask python app, than in simplified version looks like this:

```
import json
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/1')
def someFunction():
    return json.dumps([{'name': 'test1', 'parameter': 'none1'},{'name': 'test2', 'parameter': 'none2'}])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

When i run it and open http://127.0.0.1:5000/1 i get the correctly formatted json file in Chrome. Now i want that JSON file to be loaded by ajax into my webpage. I know that i have to use jsonp due to using different ports. Below my jQuery code:

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/1",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: 'application/jsonp; charset=utf-8',

        // go through the data
        success: function(data){
            console.log("success");
        },
        
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("fail");
        }

    })
```

Now, when called this returns "fail". And I am not sure why. The only differences i can see are in the flask log. When i access the website through Chrome i get:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2017 14:29:08] "GET /1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Whereas when i run AJAX query, flask shows:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2017 14:29:18] "GET /1?callback=jQuery1124005765263480826932_1502108954854&_=1502108954855 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I am open for suggestions here, i had problems with these being different ports but using jsonp solved that (no more errors.). however, i am not sure why the loading fails.

Comment: Are you sure the format of the response is JSONP?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - based on the code above, it isn't, it just outputs regular JSON.

Comment: I thought, from what i've read, that jsonp is for situations when webpage and flask are on different ports. Nevertheless, using jsonp results in the same problem, see also comments in the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`jsonify()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.json.jsonify) to create a JSON response with proper HTTP headers out of a python object. In your controller, it would be:

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/1')
def someFunction():
    return jsonify([{'name': 'test1'}])
```

And in your front-end, all you need is `dataType: json`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/1",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data){
        console.log("success");
    },

    error: function (data) {
        console.log("fail");
    }
})
```

Also note that you don't need to put the full `http://localhost:5000` in the URL. `/1` is automatically resolved to that.

Comment: This is what i did before.  
The `http://localhost:5000/1` is because i have different ports for the webpage and the flask.  
I have also tested the http/java code with the python-generated file and it worked fine, the problem occurs only when using flask.

Comment: Just changed python code to jsonify() and the problem remains, as in ajax returns "fail" with the exact code you wrote. Still think its a problem of different ports.

Comment: Can you visit http://localhost:5000/1 in your browser? Also give the route a proper name like /test.

Comment: Yes i can visit it and i see a nice json structured file

Comment: What does "different port for the webpage and the flask" mean?

Comment: Flask runs on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/1` and my website on `http://127.0.0.1:64561/index.html`

Comment: Try printing out the error in error () function. Something like error: function(a, b, c) {console.log (a); console.log (b); console.log (c); } I forgot what arguments are called, but there are three of them.

Comment: `Error: jQuery112408379380560809042_1502178429972 was not called
    at Function.error (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:)
    at h.jsonp.b.dataTypes.(anonymous function).b.converters.script json (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:4:)
    at Xb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:4:)
    at y (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:4:)
    at HTMLScriptElement.b.onload.b.onreadystatechange (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:4:)`

Comment: a is an object and b states ´parseerror´. Above i copied c

Comment: Are you still using `jsonp` datatype? It's probably failing to parse the data. Make sure to set dataType to json not jsonp.

Comment: If i use json instead of jsonp i get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:5000/1. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:64561' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: It seems you have two separate websites running on localhost, and you are trying to ajax your flask route from a separate website. Of course you're going to run into access control problems because ajax is not allowed on different origin. What you should do is create a route in your secondary app that requests the json from the flask app on the backend. Then you can ajax that route from your secondary website.

Comment: I am not sure i understood that, nor how would i try to fix that, specifically the `What you should do is create a route in your secondary app that requests the json from the flask app on the backend`. Do you have any recommended reading/video that could help me understand that.